# Как правильно расширить класс через prototype, чтобы можно было использовать приватные поля

Tags: typescript

Собственно есть класс библиотеки, который я расширяю с помощью prototype.

Чтобы не компилятор не ругался на это, я расширил тип следующим образом:

```js
declare module 'iqbus-js-client' {
    interface BusClient {
        createCommandOnlySender: (commandDescriptor: CommandDescriptor) => Promise<CommandSender>;
        createDocumentOnlySender: (documentDescriptor: DocumentDescriptor) => Promise<DocumentSender>;
        createCommandOnlyReceiver: (subscribeCommand: SubscribeCommand, callback: CommandReceiverCallback) => Promise<CommandReceiver>;
        createDocumentOnlyReceiver: (subscribeCommand: SubscribeDocument, callback: DocumentReceiverCallback) => Promise<DocumentReceiver>;
    }
}
```

Но столкнулся с тем, что не могу использовать внутри приватные методы, к которым я теперь имею доступ

Ошибки вида `TS2341: Property 'checkBusAvailable' is private and only accessible within class 'BusClient'`

Собственно, как правильно такое решить?

Версия TS: 3.9.3
Пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bush-yv94w

Comment: "Чтобы не компилятор не ругался"© - вы излишне строги к нему, хотя, в некоторых случаях я разделяю ваши чувства

Comment: не нашёл в вашем примере `checkBusAvailable`

Comment: Это приватный метод класса BusClient

Comment: @qwabra имеется ввиду, что я пишу `BusClient.prototype.anotherMethod = function() {}` и внутри пытаюсь использовать приватные методы, потому что я уже имею доступ к ним

Comment: sry, я не знаю что имеется и что отсутствует, хорошо когда автор приводит код, ещё лучше, когда автор приводит Минимальный Тестовый пример (чтобы было проще понять, но можно было повторить)

Comment: [пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjgLhgEjjAvDAZgVzMKAS3BgAoBKGAbxgF8AoOAOjAEMBbAUwxgHZGmEEFwAiIHrnxESFavRgKYUABaEILDp3oNmQ0SABMPPZzEH69SQWJgYJs6RVqkqSlXmKn6tl20XCYFCcAE5YrMDcqHKKMD6cSGA47ABGIR4K9iAUSABuIIQAJul2wqaG2TB5hdpAA)

Comment: ах, ДА ! почему-то никто не указывает версию TS, странно

Comment: @qwabra добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

### Вопрос

*как показывает мой личный опыт, вопрос в заголовке - плохая затея (не замечается)*

---

#### Изначальный вопрос автора:

> Как правильно расширить класс через prototype, чтобы можно было использовать приватные поля

#### Немного изменил:

- Как использовать приватные поля при расширении класса?
- Как обратиться к приватным переменным при расширении класса?

#### Замечание:

В этом ответе не рассматривается расширение конструктора со стороны JS (прототипы и т.д. и т.п.).
В этом ответе рассматривается вопрос исключительно со стороны типизации.

---

### Короткий ответ:

#### Официальный - никак

> Allow interfaces to declare protected members and allow implementors to implement protected and private members. [#3854](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3854)
>    Closed *benliddicott* opened this issue on **14 Jul 2015** · 7 comments
>
> ...
>
> **mhegazy** commented on 1 Dec 2017 ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3854#issuecomment-348559309))
>
> Looking at this again, i do not see how this can be done in a safe manner. a private member specifically can not match any other declaration other than itself, otherwise there are no guarantees whatsoever about type safety in the class declaring it (keep in mind that ambient classes do not have types for their private members).

#### Хотя ...

Если поменять `private` на `protected` - то всё очень просто и "из коробки".

- `function (this: Cl) {}`
- `type $q = { foo(this: Cl): void }`

#### Если нельзя, но очень хочется - то можно

*В будущем эта переменная может быть удалена и вы не получите никакого сообщения от компилятора* при использовании этого способа, однако о нём стоит знать.

---

Если вам срочно, вот прям здесь и сейчас, нужно **в одной строчке** обратиться к приватной переменной, и вам **плевать на безопасность**, то:

```
q: { // solution 0 - is the most common solution

    // всемогущий
    // @ts-ignore

    // и его новый брат
    // @ts-expect-error
}
```

---

### Расширенный ответ, с различными примерами:

*Здесь будут рассмотрены разные способы решения проблемы.*

---

#### Демонстрация проблемы - входные данные.

Дано:

```
class Cl {
    private _priv = '!_somePrVar'
    protected _guard = '!_somePrVar'
    pub = ''
}
```

Проблема:

```
q: { // problem demonstration
    class ClExt extends Cl {
        foo() {
            this._guard // OK
            // this._priv // Property '_priv' is private and only accessible within class 'Cl'.
        }
    }
    const q = function (this: Cl) {
        this._guard // ok
        // this._priv // Property '_priv' is private and only accessible within class 'Cl'.
    }
}
```

#### Способ 1

Через локальную переменную.

```
q: { // solution 1
    interface ClPrList {
        _priv: Cl['_priv']
    }
    qq: { // Err
        const q = function (this: Cl & ClPrList) {
            // this._priv // Property '_priv' has conflicting declarations and is inaccessible in type 'Cl & ClPrList'.
        }
    }
    qq: { // Err
        const isQ = (q: any): q is ClPrList => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(q)
        const q = function (this: Cl) {
            this._guard // ok
            if (isQ(this)) {
                // this._priv // Property '_priv' has conflicting declarations and is inaccessible in type 'Cl & ClPrList'.
            }
        }
    }
    qq: { // Ok
        const q = function (this: Cl) {
            this._guard // ok
            const self: ClPrList = this as any
            self._priv // ok
        }
    }
}
```

#### Способ 2

В случае, если у вас много функций, и/или внутри них много обращений к приватным переменным, то этот способ предпочтительней, и вообще - он мне нравится! :)

```
q: { // solution 2
    qq: { // problem: `generic` does not know about private and public property
        type keys<T> = keyof T
        let keys: keys<Cl> // let keys: "pub"
    }
    qq: { // solution: пилите шура, пилите© всё ручками
        /**
            Interface 'ClPrList' incorrectly extends interface 'Cl'.
            Property '_priv' is private in type 'Cl' but not in type 'ClPrList'.
         */
        // @ts-expect-error
        // @ts-ignore
        interface clExt extends Cl {
            _priv: Cl['_priv'] // 
        }
        const q = function (this: clExt) {
            this._priv // ok
            this._guard // ok
        }
    }
}
```

#### Способ 3. Будьте внимательны при чтении.

Это просто пример!

Вы вряд ли будете использовать этот код.

И тем не менее...

```
q: { // solution 3
    /**
        Interface 'ClExt' incorrectly extends interface 'Cl'.
        Types have separate declarations of a private property '_priv'.
     */
    // @ts-expect-error
    // @ts-ignore
    interface ClExt extends Cl { }
    class ClExt {
        private _priv: Cl['_priv']
        foo() {
            this._priv
            this._guard
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Замечания к ответу.

#### 0

Я пишу в коде

```
    // @ts-expect-error
    // @ts-ignore
```

это означает что надо бы, по идее, наверное писать `// @ts-expect-error`, но он у меня не работает.

#### 1

Да, верно, необходимо перечислять все приватные поля ручками :(

См.: `// problem:`generic`does not know about private and public property`

#### 2

Мне нравится второй способ.

#### 3

Можно просто поменять `private` на `protected`.

#### 4

Я не знаю что тут написать, однако вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой "править" и дополнить мой ответ.